# CSS not applied to icon inside A tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want to apply different colors to a few font-awesome icons inside an A tag. However, the CSS class seems not to be applied? I want grey (inactive icon) and yellow (active icon), but I get blue (active icon) and black (inactive icon) which I assume is Bootstrap defaults.

```
Visit https://jsfiddle.net/q1um77ax/1/ for a fiddle
```

NOTE:
The colors must be applied using classes as I am making dynamics theme features to my site and the same class tag is in several CSS files with different colors depending on the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use the appropriate classes, use this for example:

```
.themeIconStatusInactive {color:red;}
```

It works!

Comment: Ok, thats a rookie mistake and I apologize :) However, on the site itself I have triple checked the use of the correct class name, and it does not work. I an using a stylesheet there. Anyone?

Comment: Try to add !important to the style as it would be overriden by another style.

Comment: Ok, turns out that the css is not reloaded. Might be a cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong css class name: `.themeIconStatusActive`

check it here: [jsfiddle.net/q1um77ax/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/q1um77ax/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have used different classes on the Icons, that's why you didn't get the css applied! replace themeIconStatusActive with iconIndicatorActive for example and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Turns it out is was a cache issue. The old CSS was still cached in the browser. Duh. Thanks guys.